# how to understand the definition of f(n)

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Why can one define such $f(n)$? I mean there I don't map $f(n)$ to only one number.

And what do the stars stand for?
Are they simply arbitrarily numbers?

Comment: Are you aware that this is [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument)?

Comment: Are you asking why there is a function $f?$ This is a proof by contradiction. It assumes $A$ is countable, and finds a contradiction. $f$ exists by the definition of countable. We don’t need to “define” $f.$

Comment: It's clear that there exists a function f. I just wanted to know why we can write $f(n)=(*,*,...,*,f(n)_n,*,...)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use descriptive titles. "how to understand the definition of f(n)" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We *don't* define $f$. Since we are assuming that $A$ is countable, then a bijection $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow A$ must exist (by the definition of “countable”). And if $n\in\Bbb N$, then $f(n)\in A$; in other words, $f(n)$ is of the form $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4,\ldots)$, where each $a_k$ belongs to $\{0,1\}$. And now the author of the proof defined $f(n)_n$ as $\alpha_n$.

And the stars are not arbitrary numbers. They are elements of $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.